# Function declaration with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, function, operators, conditional-operator

Is it possible to use a ternary operator to declare the function name?

```
var foo,
    bar = 'bar';

(foo || bar) = function(){ // Invalid left-hand side in assignment [Bad assignment]
    alert(true);
};

[foo || bar] = function(){ // Invalid left-hand side in assignment [Bad assignment]
    alert(true);
};

(foo ? foo : bar) = function(){ // Invalid left-hand side in assignment [Bad assignment]
    alert(true);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this[foo || bar] = function(){alert(true)}
```

Thing is, if `bar` equals "bar", you're going to overwrite yourself with a function...

Comment: Ok, works in my case as described above, however not in my real world example: http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/2pk9y/5/

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is something like this?

```
window[foo ? foo : bar] = function (){
    alert(true);
};
```

Please note that "window" is not available in some environment, though all the browsers should have it.

Comment: Ok, works in my case as described above, however not in my real world example: http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/2pk9y/5/

Comment: alert(typeof $.fx.step._default);
alert(typeof $.Tween.propHooks._default.set);

Adding these 2 lines in your code may help you understand it. One is "undefined" and the other one is "function". Of course you cannot use them to name your function.